# Toast message does not appear if the user click on sign up or login, also the favourite button on home fragment are always checked

Tags: sqlite, android-studio, authentication, android-fragments

i wrote a toast message that when the user click on sign up or log in a toast message pop up, but when i sign up the app continue without toast message, also when the user enters the app all the pictures favourite button are checked, how can i make them only checked if the user clicks on them?

---

Signup.class

```
public class Signup extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText username, password, repassword, email;
Button signup, login;
FavDB DB;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);
    username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    repassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.repassword);
    signup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsignup);
    login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
    DB = new FavDB(this);

    signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String user = username.getText().toString();
            String pass = password.getText().toString();
            String repass = repassword.getText().toString();

            if (user.equals("")|| pass.equals("")|| repass.equals(""))
            Toast.makeText(Signup.this,"Please Enter All Information", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else {
                if (pass.equals(repass)){
                    Boolean checkuser = DB.checkusername(user);
                    if (checkuser==false){
                        Boolean insert = DB.insertData(user, pass);
                        if (insert==true) {
                            Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "Registered Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeFragment.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(Signup.this,"Registered Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "User Already Exists, Please Login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    }else {
                    Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "Password Not Matching",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                } }});
    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Login.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }); }
```

---

login.class

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText username, password;
Button btn_login;
FavDB DB;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    //getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    btn_login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
    DB = new FavDB(this);

    btn_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String user = username.getText().toString();
            String pass = password.getText().toString();

            if (user.equals("") || pass.equals(""))
                Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Please enter Username and Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else {
                Boolean checkuserpass = DB.checkusernamepassword(user, pass);
                if (checkuserpass == true) {
                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Login successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeFragment.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    //finish();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Invalid Entries", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } } }
    }); }}
```

---

MainActivity.class

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

    AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_dashboard, R.id.navigation_notifications)
            .build();
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController);
}}
```

---

HomeFragment.class "where the signup and login should direct to"

```
  public class HomeFragment extends Fragment{


    private ArrayList<DrawingItem> drawingItems = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = root.findViewById(R.id.recycleView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new DrawingAdapter(drawingItems, getActivity()));
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        drawingItems.add(new DrawingItem(R.drawable.girl_with_a_pearl_earing, "Girls with a pearl Earring","0","0",getString(R.string.drawing1_desc)));
        drawingItems.add(new DrawingItem(R.drawable.self_portait_ear, "Self Portrait Ear","1","0",getString(R.string.drawing2_desc)));
        drawingItems.add(new DrawingItem(R.drawable.vase, "Vase with 12 Sunflowers","2","0",getString(R.string.drawing3_desc)));
        drawingItems.add(new DrawingItem(R.drawable.night_cafe, "Coffee Terrace at Night","3","0",getString(R.string.drawing4_desc)));
        drawingItems.add(new DrawingItem(R.drawable.gurnica, "Guernica","4","0",getString(R.string.drawing5_desc)));
        drawingItems.add(new DrawingItem(R.drawable.the_scream, "The Scream","5","0",getString(R.string.drawing6_desc)));
        drawingItems.add(new DrawingItem(R.drawable.the_falling_rocket, "Nocturne in Black and Gold, the Falling Rocket","6","0",getString(R.string.drawing7_desc)));
        drawingItems.add(new DrawingItem(R.drawable.monalisa, "Monalisa","7","0",getString(R.string.drawing8_desc)));
        drawingItems.add(new DrawingItem(R.drawable.impresstion_sunrise, "Impression, Sunrise","8","0",getString(R.string.drawing9_desc)));
        drawingItems.add(new DrawingItem(R.drawable.the_last_supper,"The Last Supper", "9","0",getString(R.string.drawing9_desc)));
        drawingItems.add(new DrawingItem(R.drawable.water_lilies, "Water Lilies","10","0",getString(R.string.drawing10_desc)));
        drawingItems.add(new DrawingItem(R.drawable.the_magpie, "The Magpie","11","0",getString(R.string.drawing11_desc)));
        return root;
    }}
```

---

Manifest

```
  <activity
        android:name=".Signup"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Login"
        android:exported="false">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="false"
        android:parentActivityName=".Signup"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
    </activity>
```

---

Database helper

```
  public class FavDB extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DBNAME = "Login";
    private static int DB_VERSION = 1;
    private static String DATABASE_NAME = "favouriteDB";
    private static String TABLE_NAME = "favoriteTable";
    public static String KEY_ID = "id";
    public static String ITEM_TITLE = "itemTitle";
    public static String ITEM_IMAGE = "itemImage";
    public static String FAVORITE_STATUS = "fStatus";
    public static String ITEM_DESC ="itemDesc";


    private static String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
            + KEY_ID + " TEXT," + ITEM_TITLE+ " TEXT,"
            + ITEM_IMAGE + " TEXT," + FAVORITE_STATUS+" TEXT,"
        + ITEM_DESC + " TEXT)";

    public FavDB(Context context) { super(context,"Login",null,DB_VERSION);}

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("create Table users(username TEXT primary key, password Text)");
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
    }
    public Boolean insertData(String username, String password){
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("username", username);
        contentValues.put("password", password);
        long result = sqLiteDatabase.insert("users", null, contentValues);
        if (result==1)return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
    public Boolean checkusername(String username){
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("Select * from users where username = ?", new String[]{username});
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    public Boolean checkusernamepassword(String username, String password){
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("Select * from users where username = ? and password = ?", new String[] {username,password});
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("drop Table if exists users");
    }
    public void insertEmpty() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        for (int x = 1; x < 13; x++) {
            cv.put(KEY_ID, x);
            cv.put(FAVORITE_STATUS, "0");
            db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null, cv);
        }
    }
    public void insertIntoTheDatabase(String item_title, int item_image, String id, String fav_status) {
        SQLiteDatabase db;
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(ITEM_TITLE, item_title);
        cv.put(ITEM_IMAGE, item_image);
        cv.put(KEY_ID, id);
        cv.put(FAVORITE_STATUS, fav_status);
      //  cv.put(ITEM_DESC,item_desc);

        db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null, cv);
        Log.d("FavDB Status", item_title + ", favstatus - "+fav_status+" - . " + cv);
    }

    public Cursor read_all_data(String id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String sql = "select * from " + TABLE_NAME + " where " + KEY_ID+"="+id+"";
        return db.rawQuery(sql,null,null);
    }

    public void remove_fav(String id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String sql = "UPDATE " + TABLE_NAME + " SET  "+ FAVORITE_STATUS+" ='0' WHERE "+KEY_ID+"="+id+"";
        db.execSQL(sql);
        Log.d("remove", id.toString());

    }
    public Cursor select_all_favorite_list() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_NAME+" WHERE "+FAVORITE_STATUS+" ='1'";
        return db.rawQuery(sql,null,null);
    }}
```

Comment: you have not created `brackets {}` in your `IF` condition. add these brackets in your if a condition like this `if (user.equals("") || pass.equals("")){Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Please enter Username and Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}`

Comment: thank you, i added the brackets but still the same the Toast message didn't show